# Javascript - Decryption of a C# AES Encryption

Tags: c#, javascript, encryption, cryptography, aes

I want to decrypt text in JavaScript.

I encrypt the text in C#. This is my C# Code for the encryption:

```
    readonly byte[] _salt = new byte[] { 48,94,2,4,9,4,52,222,12,65 };

    private string getEncryptedString(string text, string password)
    {
        string retCryptedString = null;
        byte[] retCryptedByteArr = null;

        retCryptedByteArr = encryptStringToBytes(text, createHash(password));

        retCryptedString = Convert.ToBase64String(retCryptedByteArr);

        return retCryptedString;
    }

    private Rfc2898DeriveBytes createHash(string password)
    {
        Rfc2898DeriveBytes hash = default(Rfc2898DeriveBytes);

        hash = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, _salt);

        return hash;
    }

    private byte[] encryptStringToBytes(string Text, Rfc2898DeriveBytes hash)
    {
        RijndaelManaged encryption = new RijndaelManaged();
        RijndaelManaged rijAlg = new RijndaelManaged();
        byte[] encrypted = null;
        ICryptoTransform encryptor;

        if (Text == null || Text.Length <= 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("No text");
        }

        rijAlg = (RijndaelManaged)Rijndael.Create();

        rijAlg.Key = hash.GetBytes(encryption.KeySize / 8);
        rijAlg.IV = hash.GetBytes(encryption.BlockSize / 8);

        encryptor = rijAlg.CreateEncryptor(rijAlg.Key, rijAlg.IV);

        using (MemoryStream ms_Encrypt = new MemoryStream())
        {

            using (CryptoStream cs_Encrypt = new CryptoStream(ms_Encrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            { 
                using (StreamWriter sw_Encrypt = new StreamWriter(cs_Encrypt))
                {
                    sw_Encrypt.Write(Text);
                }

                encrypted = ms_Encrypt.ToArray();
            }
        }

        return encrypted;
    }
```

I tried lots of libraries (e.g. crypto-js). But I can't decrypt it, because I don't know how to generate the key and the iv.

When I generate the PBKDF2 key, I can't add it to the decryption.

Comment: Why decrypt it in javascript ? You could decrypt it in a generic handler then return the value to the client side. You do not want your decryption code to be seen for users to hack.

Comment: I have a webservice in C#. And an App in Javascript. When the app calls a method, the webservice encrypts the answer and the app should decrypt and show the decrypted answer.

Comment: I have provided an answer possibly this may help instead of the generic handler I am sure you could handle request and response with the web service.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Generic Handler
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
string EncryptedString = context.Request.QueryString["encrypted"];
response.write(decryptedString(EncryptedString);
}


//javascript

$.get("MyHandler.ashx?encrypted=YourEncryptedString").done(function(response){
var DecryptedString = response
});
```

Comment: Okay, but why should I encrypt a webservice answer, when I decrypt the answer on the same site?
Ahm, am I understand it right, will the answer on the transport encrypted and after receiving on the App automate decrypted?

Comment: It does not need to be on the same site, the purpose is to still have your decryption in c# then transport the decrypted string back to the requester(client) Yes it will transport encrypted.With my example you could achive decrypted text with any service that handles HttpContext.

Comment: Okay, and the generic handler lays on the server or in the App?
How is the sequence?
The App calls a method from the webservice. The webservice encrypt the answer. The App gets the encrypted anwers. The App calls the generic handler with the encrypted answer and gets the decrypted answer. Is that right?

Comment: If your app is in asp.net/mvc you will want it on the app, and yest that is correct.

Comment: No, no ASP.Net/MVC. My app is written in JavaScript (Apache Cordova). So I don't know how to include the generic handler.

Comment: You will need to put it on your web service instead of the application then.